# Problema con Arraylist y JComboBox

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con una parte de un ejercicio, en una clase llamada BBDD tengo un método que se conecta a una base de datos y mete en un Arraylist todos los jugadores con sus resoectivos datos y hace un return. El método es este:

```
public ArrayList<Jugador> arrayListJugadores() throws SQLException {
      Connection conn = conexion();
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String consulta = "SELECT * FROM jugadores ORDER BY nombre";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);    
      ArrayList<Jugador> jugadoresLista = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        int codigo = rs.getInt("codigo");
        String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
        String procedencia = rs.getString("procedencia");
        String altura = rs.getString("altura");
        int peso = rs.getInt("peso");
        String posicion = rs.getString("posicion");
        String equipo = rs.getString("equipo");
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador(codigo, nombre, procedencia, altura, peso, posicion, equipo);
        jugadoresLista.add(jugador);
      }
      conn.close();
      return jugadoresLista;
   }
```

Mi problema esta en que tengo una clase accesoria de la interfaz gráfica llamada Modificar y en esa clase tengo que cargar en un JCombo solamente los nombres de los jugadores que están en el Arraylist, es lo que me tiene atascado para luego poder continuar con el actionPerformed una vez resuelto, y no consigo hacerlo. Os dejo la parte dónde va el JCombo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Modificar implements ActionListener {
   
   //Atributos
   private JDialog dialogo;
   private JComboBox<Jugador> jugadores;
   private JTextField cajaAltura;
   private JTextField cajaPeso;
   private JTextField cajaPosicion;
   private JTextField cajaEquipo;
   private JButton cambiar;
   private ClaseBBDD estaBBDD;
   
   // Constructor
   public DialogoModificar(ClaseBBDD unaBBDD) {
   
      this.estaBBDD = unaBBDD;
      
      // Creamos y configuramos un JDialog
      dialogo = new JDialog();
      dialogo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      
      // Creamos un contenedor para organizar la zona norte 
      JPanel norte = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      norte.add(new JLabel("Jugador"));

      // Carga el desplegable jugadores con los jugadores de la BBDD
      ArrayList<Jugador> listaJugadores = estaBBDD.arrayListJugadores();

      norte.add(jugadores);
      jugadores.addActionListener(this);
      dialogo.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, norte);
      
      // Creamos un contenedor para organizar la zona centro 
      JPanel centro = new JPanel();
      centro.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 4));
      centro.add(new JLabel("Altura: "));
      cajaAltura = new JTextField(15);
      centro.add(cajaAltura);
      centro.add(new JLabel("Peso: "));
      cajaPeso = new JTextField(15);
      centro.add(cajaPeso);
      centro.add(new JLabel("Posición: "));
      cajaPosicion = new JTextField(15);
      centro.add(cajaPosicion);
      centro.add(new JLabel("Equipo: "));
      cajaEquipo = new JTextField(15);
      centro.add(cajaEquipo);
      dialogo.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, centro);
      
      // Creamos el botón y lo añadimos a la ventana principal
      cambiar = new JButton("CAMBIAR");
      cambiar.addActionListener(this);
      dialogo.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, cambiar);
      
      // Ajustamos la ventana a los componentes y la hacemos visible
      dialogo.pack();
      dialogo.setVisible(true);
   }
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola Kop, parecería que se te olvido parte del código de la clase **Modificar**, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que falta?, además, si recibes mensajes de error agregalos (siempre como texto):

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema o error? ¿Desde dónde estás llamando a `arrayListJugadores()` y qué haces posteriomente con la respuesta?

Comment: @MarcePuente, he añadido el código que faltaba de la clase, salvo el metodo actionPerformed, que de momento no lo necesito porque primero quiero meter en JComboBox los nombres de los jugadores del arraylist.

Comment: @A.Cedano, el problema como he explicado, es que no sé como meter los nombres de los jugadores del arraylist en el JComboBox, eso es todo, a partir de ahí ya me sabré continuar, pero esa parte se me ha atragantado. Si puedes mira el código, he edidtado la parte de la llamada del arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré la manera más eficaz de conseguir los nombres de los jugadores del arraylist:

```
jugadores = new JComboBox<Jugador>();
      try {
         ArrayList<Jugador> listaJugadores = estaBBDD.arrayListJugadores();
         for (Jugador jugador : listaJugadores) {
            jugadores.addItem(jugador);
         }
      } catch (SQLException excepcion) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, excepcion.getMessage());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

según entiendo, te falta solo cargar la lista de equipos en el **ComboBox**... vamos con ello.

```
  // cargamos la lista de jugadores
ArrayList<Jugador> listaJugadores = estaBBDD.arrayListJugadores();

  // creamos un array de nombres
String jugadores[] = new String[ listaJugadores.length ];

  // cargamos el array, con los nombres de ellos
for( int i = 0; i < jugadores.length; i ++ ) {
    jugadores[ i ] = listaJugadores[ i ].getNombre();
}     

  // creamos e inicializamos el combo con la lista de jugadores
JComboBox <String> listadoDeJugadores = new JComboBox<>( jugadores );
```

Y ya tienes el Combo con la lista.

Comment: Lo he estado probando y no me funciona, he visto que el error podría estar en que defines una variable jugadores como un array de String con una longitud determinada por listaJugadores.length, y luego, en el for estás tratando de inicializar cada elemento de ese array con un valor específico. Sin embargo, en la instrucción String jugadores[i] = listaJugadores[i].getNombre();, estás definiendo una nueva variable jugadores[i], en lugar de asignar un valor al elemento existente en la posición i.

Comment: Gracias por la observación, tienes toda la razón, ya edité mi respuesta, espero que te sirva.